# Ubuntu 18.04 wierd symbol above status bar, is my system hacked?

Tags: xubuntu

I am having this weird icon in Ubuntu 18.04 from a few days. My laptop is having a wierd black icon in the shape of a person just above the status bar. You can check it at screenshot below
[image]

If I restart my system, it disappears but it randomly appears. I am not sure what it is and it feel as if my system is hacked or something.
If anyone knows about this, please let me know.

Comment: are you sure someone isn't prancing you with some kind of script or program? has anyone been on your laptop without your knowledge? just checking if it might be a prank program or something like that cause you never know. and if it isn't what have you recently installed?

Comment: No, I didn't use external hardware and this is my personal laptop so no one accesses it. I only use web browser on laptop and sometimes watch movies. That's it, I don't know what has caused this. :(

Comment: i never asked about external hardware, i asked if software has recently been installed, should have added software to it, but do you have a virus scanner on your laptop?

Comment: Hey delfiler, I am not using any virus scanner on ubuntu 18.04. Recently I only installed vscode application

Comment: sorry for the late reation but i was needed but i am back now, so did vscode ask to install something else beside itself? like a addon or something like that and did you follow any tutorials or did it completely yourself? i know a lot of questions and no solutions but the more info we have the better we can help you

Comment: No, this symbol is showing from before and it randomly shows. When it shows, it doesn't disappear and I can't click it either.

Comment: okay well if you think you are hacked what happens if you are unplugged from the internet? does it appear in the same time frame? and i would suggest doing a  full-system-virus-scan on your laptop just to be safe

Comment: Any suggestions for virus scan ? I randomly see that icon on my system. I am not sure what triggers it but I will scan it with a virus scanner just to be feel safe.

Comment: well you can use clamav which is a free ubuntu virus scanner

Comment: Will give it a try delfiler, hope it is able to detect something.

Comment: let's hope yeah and did it find anything?

Comment: No results of malware from the antivirus :( Is there any terminal command which can give me details of what is running at that moment so that I can run it whenever I see that icon ?

Comment: are you sure you want to use that one? cause that is a lot of digging and checking to see if it is the right program